# javascript Split hierarchical tree into all the sub-trees and group the nodes of each sub-tree by its level

Tags: javascript, algorithm, tree

I have a hierarchical structure data, and can be treat as a tree structure.

**First**

I need to split this hierarchical tree into sub-tree and get all the sub-trees.
The function below is how I did, it works well

```
            var hierarchObjects = [];
            traverseNodes(root);
            function traverseNodes(root){
                hierarchObjects.push(root);
                for(var i=0; i<root.children.length; ++i)
                {
                    traverseNodes(root.children[i]);
                }
            }
```

**Second**

I need to group the nodes for each level of a subtree, in Array `hierarchObjects`. And the depth of the sub-tree is different.

For example,

put nodes of a sub-tree of level1 in array `Level1`.

put nodes of a sub-tree of level2 in array `Level2`.

So What should I do for `Second` process?

Is there a more efficient way for all the process?

Because My dataset is a bit big, and there are about 1300 sub-trees, I need to find an efficient way?

My dataset is a tree structure: http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~yongnan/untitled/pathwayHierarchy.json

You can see it is a `parent`-----`children` structure tree.

For this tree I use step 1 to split into sub-trees.
For each sub-tree, example as below:

**1**

```
  {
        "dbId": "111461",
        "name": "Cytochrome c-mediated apoptotic response",
        "children": [
            {
                "dbId": "111458",
                "name": "Formation of apoptosome",
                "children": [],
                "size": 1
            },
            {
                "dbId": "111459",
                "name": "Activation of caspases through apoptosome-mediated cleavage",
                "children": [],
                "size": 1
            }
        ]
    }
```

for this sub-tree, it just has two children for level1, so the return array should be [[Formation of apoptosome,Activation of caspases through apoptosome-mediated cleavage ]]

**2**

```
 {
        "dbId": "111471",
        "name": "Apoptotic factor-mediated response",
        "children": [
            {
                "dbId": "111461",
                "name": "Cytochrome c-mediated apoptotic response",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "dbId": "111458",
                        "name": "Formation of apoptosome",
                        "children": [],
                        "size": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "dbId": "111459",
                        "name": "Activation of caspases through apoptosome-mediated cleavage",
                        "children": [],
                        "size": 1
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "dbId": "111469",
                "name": "SMAC-mediated apoptotic response",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "dbId": "111463",
                        "name": "SMAC binds to IAPs ",
                        "children": [],
                        "size": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "dbId": "111464",
                        "name": "SMAC-mediated dissociation of IAPcaspase complexes ",
                        "children": [],
                        "size": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

for this dataset, the result could be

[
[Cytochrome c-mediated apoptotic response,SMAC-mediated apoptotic response],
 [Formation of apoptosome,Activation of caspases through apoptosome-mediated cleavage,SMAC binds to IAPs, SMAC-mediated dissociation of IAPcaspase complexes]
]

Now, I am trying to use Breadth first algorithm to do the *Second* step. I know the efficient is not very good.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you make an example of root object and the desired output?

Comment: Something like this? : http://jsfiddle.net/fmhrpdbf/

Comment: thanks, although the speed is still slow

Comment: BFS travels each node only once, and its main problem is memory needed, so no reason there is one faster. Also, at least in my browser it takes 1 milisecond to generate the output from the data from your link : http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/fmhrpdbf/1/ check how long it takes in console

Comment: thanks, the speed is acceptable.

Comment: Alright, will post as answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, and unless you are handling around 1m nodes or very deep trees, should be pretty fast:

```
var data={
    //your data
}


var arr=[]; // array that holds an array of names for each sublevel

function traverse(data, level){
    if(arr[level]==undefined) arr[level]=[]; // if its the first time reaching this sub-level, create array
    arr[level].push(data.name); // push the name in the sub-level array
    for(var index=0;index<data.children.length;index++){ // for each node in children
        traverse(data.children[index], level+1); // travel the node, increasing the current sub-level
    }
}

traverse(data, 0); // start recursive function
console.log(arr)
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/juvian/fmhrpdbf/1/